# What is the Python ` symbol

Tags: python

Lots of old python code I look in has this ` symbol around a lot of stuff, what does it do? Now it is not considered valid syntax, obviously.

And I don't think it is just another string identifier, its sometimes wrapped around functions in the code I'm looking at.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That must be *very* old code, or else written by someone writing Python 2 who chose backticks to make it compatible with Python 1.5.2 rather than use `repr()`  to make it compatible with Python 3. Treat code from that source with scepticism.